# Installed Munin on CentOS, but it does not generate data

Tags: munin

I've installed Munin on CentOS, in Munin directory, it only has a few files and I could not see the website data. The Munin log shows the connection to 127.0.0.1 was refused. I have tried to disable iptables and it gives the same error.

#### Error log

2011/05/06 15:30:01 Opened log file
2011/05/06 15:30:01 [INFO]: Starting munin-update
2011/05/06 15:30:02 Failed to connect to node 127.0.0.1:4949/tcp : Connection refused
2011/05/06 15:30:02 [ERROR] Munin::Master::UpdateWorker failed to connect to node
2011/05/06 15:30:02 [INFO] Reaping Munin::Master::UpdateWorker.  Exit value/signal: 20/0
2011/05/06 15:30:02 [INFO] No old data available for failed worker localhost;localhost.  This node will disappear from the html web page hierarchy
2011/05/06 15:30:02 [INFO]: Munin-update finished (0.02 sec)

#### Munin directory

-rw-r--r--  1 munin  munin  2.5K May  6 15:05 definitions.html
-rw-r--r--  1 munin  munin  2.0K May  6 15:05 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 munin  munin  1.8K May  6 15:05 logo-h.png
-rw-r--r--  1 munin  munin   473 May  6 15:05 logo.png
-rw-r--r--  1 munin  munin  5.3K May  6 15:05 style.css

Comment: Do you have munin-node running? (/etc/init.d/munin-node start)

Comment: I only have one machine, isn't munin-node for multiple machines?

Comment: You need munin-node on every machine you want to monitor. Even if you have only one node you want to monitor.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. The instruction in Linode wiki gave the wrong information. http://library.linode.com/server-monitoring/munin/fedora-14